# Is it possible to hide from webpage that you are browsing from phone in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

There is a webpage that won't let me use all the benefits from it because I am browsing from phone. Is it possible to tell webpage that device I am browsing from is not android phone? I would like to use WebView or something else if this is possible. So, I want to make an application for my own use, so I can go to that webpage from my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website is restricting some contents because of screen size, you can select "Request desktop site" (see below 1), most of the cases, the website would deliver contents as if you are using a big screen computer.  You still have "Android" in your user agent.

If the website is detecting device type from User Agent and do things different, you can use *Firefox*,  install an Add-on (below 2) "User-Agent Switcher and Manager", and then select any user agent string you want (below 3).

[image]

Comment: Really stupid of me not to think of Desktop mode. Thank you so much! Regards